# When rails app create database and collection when using MongoDb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am new to rails.In the case of sqlite rails app make changes in db when ever we run migrations. but if we uses mongodb when it make changes in  db??. thanks in advance for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections in mongodb are created on the fly when the first document is inserted.

When using rails with mongoid you would create the database first with `rake db:create`.

- https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/

Comment: I would recommend that you learn Rails with ActiveRecord before stepping into Mongoid. There are better learning resources that let you focus on learning the rails fundamentals and how to structure good rails apps.

Answer (score 0):

rake db:create exists only for dependency purposes, it does not actually do anything. rake db:setup creates indexes and seeds the database from seeds file.